# Is it possible to reliably test or measure one's ability to taste?

Tags: test, reference-request, taste

For one's eyesight and hearing capability, there are tests that allow doctors to quantitatively assess how well these senses perform. With regards to people's ability to taste, I don't know any of such tests.

I wonder whether a test exists that can quantitatively assess to what degree how well a person can taste along the five taste dimensions: bitter, salty, sour, sweet, and umami. In addition, it would be interesting to read about such tests if any academic publications on them exist.

Comment: There are tests to determine the ability to detect certain molecules; these are usually genetically determined. Did you search "how to determine level of taste"? If you do, you will find some articles about it. Mostly, though, taste, like pain, is subjective. Using a scale of 1 to 10, we can't really know the level of pain someone is feeling when they call it "a 6" and another calls it "a 10". Some people call everything a 10, leading to one exasperated nurse telling a patient, "*Ten* is when someone cuts off your leg with a chainsaw and sets the stump on fire." <- True story.